# Is it possible customize the QML TableView headerDelegate individually?

Tags: qt, qml, tableview

In QML TableView, is possible customize the header, using headerDelegate, but the style applied, work for all columns.

Example:

```
headerDelegate: Rectangle {
    height: 20
    color: "red"

    Text {
        text: styleData.value
        color: "#FFF"
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        font.pointSize: 18
        minimumPointSize: 3
        fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }
}
```

Is it possible apply the style individually?
For example: In the first column background blue and the second column background red

Or exist another way to customize the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there exist more elegant ways for the `TableView` in particular, but a common approach to customize delegates in general is to use the provided information.

For the basic usecase of having different colors, you can just have it:

```
headerDelegate: Rectangle {
    color: ["red", "blue"][styleData.column % 2]
}
```

For more complex things, you can make the delegate a `Loader` which loads different `sourceComponents` depending on the information you have available for the delegate.

Comment: the basic use case is to have better colors, dropdown arrows, proper margins/paddings, a line right to the field to resize it, and potentially a border bottom line. Your delegate does not even draw a header text

Comment: @IceFire: The question was about applying styleing not about replicating lines from the OPs example. That the OP is able to draw header texts was obvious from his example. This answer is deliberately focused on the question and not about any other "basic usecases" you might see, but the OP didn't ask for. If asked for all basic usecases you list, the question would lack focus (multiple questions at once, see closing reasons for questions)

Comment: You used the word "basic use case" which is never in any professional application a "basic use case". Too many "let's make the header pink" examples float around that hinder proper development because you need to first dig through 10 examples until, FINALLY, one is at least remotely in common with real applications. So, no, a better answer would include all my mentioned things because tons of people find this thread here searching for a good solution

Comment: When I was developing UIs with Qt in a professional embedded context, I never had the usecase for any dropdown arrows or resizeing lines. Also none of your needs have been requested in the question. The question was, how can I go beyond the limitations of styleData to only have one style applied to all header delegates. And there are IMHO two levels: 1. (Basic) only having differing values based on the column in otherwise identical components. 2. (Advanced) having varying components. But ofc, you might not find your needs here and you may have your opinion. But maye its the wrong question.